# C Pointers & Linked Lists

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I am coding a simple C employee database program through the use of (single) linked lists. At the moment I am trying to write the "delete employee" function, which is given below.

I am trying to cycle through the linked list using the while loop, and STOP when the current pointer name field matches the name the user wishes to delete. (Stored in linestore.)

For some reason, it just keeps looping through the database till the end no matter what. I have tried printing the contents of linestore & currptr->name at each stage, and they appear correct, so I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Delete Employee function:

```
char *lineptr;
char linestore[300];
lineptr = &linestore;

struct Employee *currptr = root;
struct Employee *prevptr = NULL;

fprintf(stderr, "\nPlease enter the EXACT name of the employee to be deleted.\n");
read_line(stdin, lineptr, MAX_NAME_LENGTH);  //linestore function is working (checked)



while ( (currptr->name != linestore) & (currptr != NULL) )
{
  fprintf(stderr, "\n***Searching database...***\n");
  fprintf(stderr, "***The current record is %s", currptr->name);
  prevptr = currptr;
  currptr = currptr->next;
}

if ( currptr->name == linestore )
{

  fprintf(stderr, "\n***Record DELETED.***\n");
}
```

Comment: you would do well to include some sample output in your question

Comment: Are you sure you want to store `&linestore` in the pointer, because it a `pointer` to the `whole array`, not to a `character` in that array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
currptr->name == linestore
```

`==` doesn't compare the values. It instead compare the pointers. For string comparison, you need to use `strncmp` function instead.

Comment: So would the while condition be replaced by: while ( (strncmp(linestore, currptr->name, 100) == 0) && (currptr != NULL) ) ?

Comment: My bad, I meant != 0.

Comment: @GeorgeLoman Barring details about length, yes. (Also, remember that you should also be using `strncmp` in the `if` statement too.)

Comment: GeorgeLoman: you should be checking that currptr is not NULL *before* you try to look at currptr->name, because NULL->name will crash your program.  So reverse the order of the && clauses in that 'while' statement.

Answer (score 1):

you should use [strncmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncmp/)

to compare names, with a specific length

```
if (strncmp (currptr->name, linestore, strLength) == 0 && (currptr != NULL) )
{
}
```

also the & should be && when comparing booleans conditions

Answer (score 1):

Use [`strcmp`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/?kw=strcmp) and generally you should use the logial `&&` instead of the bitwise `&` for what you are doing.
`==` and `!=` compare your **pointers**, not the *content* (the chars) behind the pointers.

Also, next time you should provide a full example of your code. Here, the implementation of your linked list is missing .. maybe you have another mistake there?

Answer (score 0):

`currptr->name != linestore`  and `currptr->name == linestore`

are incorrect, you have to use `strcmp()` or `strncmp()`

Answer (score 0):

I see two things:

1) You want to compare strings using `strcmp()/strncmp()`. Using `==` will check to see if they are stored in the same location in memory.

2) You probably wanted `&&` instead of `&` in the condition for that `while` loop. `&` is a bitwise and, while `&&` is the logical and.

Answer (score 0):

There are two errors in the program.

First one is to Use

```
    strcmp(currptr->name,linestore)
```

And next one is you are using bitwise operator '&' instead of logical and '&&' operator.

```
   while (strcmp(currptr->name, linestore) && (currptr != NULL))
```